# Php header content on css light box

Tags: php, css, lightbox, lightbox2

based on this [web](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), i like to use that light box to show image that was generated by this php code :

```
<?php
include "libchart/classes/libchart.php";

header("Content-type: image/png");

$chart = new VerticalBarChart(700,250);

$dataSet = new XYDataSet();
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Bekasi", 873));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Jakarta", 10));
$chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

$chart->setTitle("UTLC testing chart");
$chart->render();
    ?>
```

my question : can we use php code with header content to generate image in that light box and show it? 
thanks anyone and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is the image already generated on the initial page load (before the user opens the light box)? Or is it supposed to be generated via PHP after the user opens the light box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightbox is a JS library therefore returning an image won't work. You can use PHP to build the response page so that the lightbox will trigger when the page has loaded however.